# Custom user access to Zimbra webmail

Tags: apache-httpd, email, authentication

I know it's a specific topic, but it could be broadened to a more general context.

I have a Zimbra mail server on CentOS, only used via webmail, where i need to differentiate user capability to login from LAN and/or external (internet).

Example:

**- User A can both login to webmail from internal client LAN, but also from his smartphone while at home, for example.**

**- User B can login only from internal LAN.**

Zimbra doesn't have builtin functions to provide this kind of differentiation, so i need to develop it somehow.

Until now I just made some tests customizing Zimbra Apache configuration, enabling a reverse proxy with htpasswd based access. It works of course, but then an user would need to provide double authentication, 1 for Apache, 1 for Zimbra webmail, and i would avoid that.

Before re-inventing the wheel, has someone stumbled upon this issue before?

So the general (less Zimbra-based) question would be: has anyone tried to forward Apache successful login to another 3rd party application/web portal? In that case, back to my specific issue, I could play around with [ZimbraCustomAuth](https://www.zimbra.com/docs/os/6.0.10/administration_guide/5_Zimbra_LDAP.05.4.html#1078126) and create a succesful SSON environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. For anyone interested a good and simple way to do it:

[Apache + mod_auth_pubtkt](https://github.com/manuelkasper/mod_auth_pubtkt): as a simple SSO manager with customizable auth backend.

[Zimbra preauth](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Preauth): Zimbra pre-authentication logic to recall in case of successful auth.